Materialized views refresh sequence when multiple MV's are getting refreshed through job
I have two Materialized views(A and B) in ORACLE.
Does Oracle run MV "A" first the run MV "B" ? or run in parallel?
Please advise on this?
job_action =>  'BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(''A'',''B''); END',

If it's getting refreshed in parallel, then how to achieve refreshing in sequence?

I think you mean REFRESH('A,B') so it's a single parameter, not two separate parameters? Experiment and find out if it follows the list order or not. If not, simply make separate refresh calls in whatever order you want without passing in a list.

more information here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/refreshing-materialized-views.html#GUID-EEB31BA4-AD51-4A90-8FB0-2238F5A41817
